# JavaScript only printing first line of XML file; Omits the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jsp

I am working on a project using JSP. I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<people>
    <person>George</person>
    <person>Mary</person>
    <person>John</person>
 </people>
```

However, when I try to pull the information from the XML file, it only prints out the name of the first person, George; but not Mary and John. Here is my function:

```
function Names() {
    var xml = getXML(); //This opens the XML file in another method.
    var getPeopleTag = xml.getElementsByTagName("people");
    for (var i = 0; i < getPeopleTag.length; i++) {
        var currentName = getPeopleTag[i];
        var getNames = currentName.getElementsByTagName("person")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        $("#printPerson").html(getNames);
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `getPeopleTag.length` is 1. You need to loop over the children of `getPeopleTag`.

Comment: For starters, you may need to use `.append` instead of `.html` as `.html` wipes off old content with new content. Also I think your iterate is not correct.

Comment: Thanks to all of you who helped. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery already, why not use it's XML parser (best if you get v1.10.2 as there is an error in previous versions), and then use jQuery to get the names of the people in the document.

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

$xml.find('.person').each(function (){
  console.log($(this).text()); // George Mary John
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/845pV/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var xml = getXML();
var txt = "";
$(xml).find("person").each(function(){
    txt += "<div>"+$(this).text()+"</div>";
});
$("body").append(txt);
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7mMRD/)